# joomla loadposition - how to set module position?

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have a custom module (custom HTML) that I want to be on a specific Article
I am using the {loadposition modulename} and it displays my custom HTML modules.  However I cannot seem to find where to change how my module is displayed - I want to place it in a specific location on my article, but where do I put in the position information for this?

Comment: can you wrap the module inside a div and give it a `inline` style.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this the {loadposition item} must be contained within a div that has css style attached

I accomplished this by doing the following:

In the article switch the editor to show the HTML code

add the {loadposition} as follows:

```
<div class="wrap">{loadposition cp_frontpage}</div>
```

I then add a css file that handles my wrap div

```
.wrap
{
text-align:center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

this can be done as an inline css, or by an external css file (as I did above)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to place the custom module in a specific location of your article page. Please follow the below steps:

The first thing you will need to do is create the module..

1. Login to the administrator panel of your Joomla installation
2. Navigate to Extensions -> Module Manager -> New and select the module you wish placed in to your article (eg. Custom HTML)
3. Set the module postion to one that does not exist in your template. To achieve this, click on the dropdown box next to the 'Position' option and simply type in a new, distinct, module position (eg articlemodule_footer. I like to give the modules a common prefix (eg articlemodule_). This allows me to easily search for my article modules at a later date.
4. Set the 'Menu Assignment' to 'All'. (Note: it will only appear on the pages with your article because it is the only place where the articlemodule_footer module position is called)
5. Setup the rest the remaining parameters for your module and click the 'Save'.

Once you have set up your module it is now time to place it inside the article(s) you wish it to appear. For this the Joomla! team has provided us with the loadposition function.

Open up the article(s) in which you wish to place your module and navigate to the area of the article with in your editor where you want the mopdule to appear and type the following...

{loadposition position}

Replacing 'position' with the position name you assigned to the module which you have just created. Eg..

{loadposition articlemodule_footer}

Click save and your done!

If you find that the module is not showing in your article be sure to check the following...

1. Navigate to Extensions -> Plugin Manager and ensure that the 'Content - Load Module' plugin is enabled.
2. Clear your site's cache and refresh the page. (Joomla Administration -> System -> Clear Cache)
3. For us to be able to display this function in this tutorial we had to place the curly brackets surrounding the function in italics. Ensure the italic styling was not copied across if you have copied the function directly from this article.

Comment: Mini Encyclopedia about Joomla Module :)

Comment: Great summary but I wouldn't set it to load on pages it is not going to display on; if you know the menu link for that article just set it to display there. It's a performance hit otherwise.

Comment: yes - if you read my question you will see I already have completed all the steps you stated.  My question is in regards to how to place it in a specific area of an article